# Как заполнить объект из значений массива?

Tags: javascript

А если конкретней **вот  код:**

```
var arr = [ 'name1', 'name2', 'name3' ];
var obj = {};
/* необходимо чтобы каждый следующий ключ объекта был "равен" каждому
следующему элементу массива, то есть, чтобы в результате получился следующий объект: 

obj {
    name1: 'любое значение';
    name2: 'любое значение';
    name3: 'любое значение';
} */

//Путь решения который, как я думал сработает: 
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ {
  var key = arr[i];
  obj[key] = 'любое значение';
}
```

**Это не работает ... -** http://plnkr.co/edit/ncUuw0RL9e7FK9jeGmLb?p=info

Comment: а что? не работает? если не считать отсутствующую закрывающуюся скобку после `i++` вполне себе работает

Comment: Нет! Не работает, может быть дело в браузере... 

http://plnkr.co/edit/ncUuw0RL9e7FK9jeGmLb?p=info

Comment: все работает :) вы просто проверяете не правильно, выводите новый объект в консоль например: `console.log(newObj)` и увидите что объект правильно заполнен. вам просто повезло что у объекта `window` есть функция `open` иначе на строке `newObj[open]` вы получили бы ошибку обращения к необъявленной переменной

Comment: Да действительно, но почему alert выдает не то, что есть ? И да если я например буду проводить проверку на наличие в объекте ключа например open то все будет работать как надо?

Comment: `alert` выдает именно то, что есть. Второй вопрос не понял.

Comment: Что-то я совсем запутался, пожалуйста объясните подробно, если вам не составит труда, что происходит и почему

Comment: добавьте в вопрос код, как вы проверяете

Comment: Обновил планкер http://plnkr.co/edit/ncUuw0RL9e7FK9jeGmLb?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

alert преобразует любой тип к строковому, аналогично использованию метода прототипа объекта toString, который возвращает строку с типом объекта (а не его свойствами):

```
({a:1,b:2}).toString() // [object Object]
```

Что бы увидеть содержимое объекта можно прибегнуть к преобразование в JSON формат:

```
JSON.stringify({a:1,b:2}); // {a:1,b:2}
```

В целом решение для вас будет следующим:

```
var arr = [ 'name1', 'name2', 'name3' ];
var obj = {};
arr.forEach(function(val) { obj[val] = Math.random(); });
alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код делает все верно , только нужно выводить правильно :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o3yt6hk3/1/